# Kubernetes MySQL Statefulset slave log sequence number is in future

Tags: mysql, database, kubernetes, percona

I  am using

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/

to run MySQL replication, MySQL master and slave was running fine.
Last week I changed the replica of MySQL statefulset to 1, to stop the MySQL slave. Now I want to start the slave, when I change statefulset replicas to 2, I was getting

```
'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'.
```

So I wanted to do a fresh clone from master, so deleted the PV on slave and recreated the slave pod, it created new PV with no data, xtrabackup cloned the files from MySQL master.

But when starting I am getting below error, (edited)

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Page [page id: space=5868, page number=1181] log sequence number 4431188670431 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 4431180574947.
```

Even though the Statefulset runs

```
"xtrabackup --prepare /var/lib/mysql"
```

slave throws this error and fails to start, any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/423516/mysql-innodb-is-in-the-future-current-system-log-sequence-number)?

Comment: yes, i tried removing the ib_logfile, ibtmp and even ibdata1... nothing helped